# External keyboard for Galaxy tablet 2 7.0

Tags: external-keyboard, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7

I'm trying to use an external keyboard with my Galaxy tablet 2 7.0.

My tablet isn't detecting the keyboard, but it works when I plug it into my computer. This keyboard uses a normal USB male to connect, but my tablet uses samsung 30-pin to male. So, I bought a female-to-female adapter. I'm assuming this is the equivalent of a USB OTG adapter but still no joy.

How do I get this keyboard to work?

Answer (score 0):

A female-to-female USB adaptor can't fill the role of a USB-on-the-go cable. A device that uses USB-OTG has the USB hardware and the drivers needed to act as a USB host *or* a USB peripheral. The wiring of the USB-OTG cable tells the device which role to act in. (The host side has two pins wired together, but the peripheral side doesn't.)

Most USB peripherals don't have the required hardware or software to act as a USB host. The Samsung Galaxy Tablet 2 7.0 *does*, but it needs a correctly wired adaptor so that it knows it's supposed to be acting as a host.

Samsung makes and sells [a 30-pin to USB host](http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/galaxy-tab-accessories/EPL-1PL0BEGSTA) adaptor, so you might be able to find one at your local electronics shop.